# HIbernate persist object only with id

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the folowing entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comprobante_pago")
public class ComprobantePago implements Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String serie;
private SocioNegocio emisor;
private Usuario usuario;


@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "comprobante_pago_id_seq",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

@Column(name = "serie")
public String getSerie() {
    return serie;
}

public void setSerie(String serie) {
    this.serie = serie;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_emisor")
public SocioNegocio getEmisor() {
    return emisor;
}

public void setEmisor(SocioNegocio emisor) {
    this.emisor = emisor;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario")
public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
}
```

I want to persist a ComprobantePago object of the following way :

```
ComprobantePago cp = new ComprobantePago();
cp.setSerie("0001");
SocioNegocio emisor = new SocioNegocio();
emisor.setId(2);
Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
usuario.seId(10);
cp.setEmisor(emisor);
cp.setUsuario(usuario);
//persist the object
comprobantePagoDAO.crearComprobantePago(cp);
```

Where the ids of usuario(10) and emisor(2) are persisted in the respective entities, I make it in this way because I have only the ids of the entities.

In another class I have the method to persist the entity

```
public class ComprobantePagoDAOImpl implements ComprobantePagoDAO {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void crearComprobantePago(ComprobantePago comprobante) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(comprobante);
}
....
}
```

thank for all.

Comment: please show the hibernate entities for Usuario and SocioNegocio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create new, detached entities with only an ID, when what you actually want to do is link your new entity with persistent, managed entities that exist in the database.

Use [`EntityManager.getReference()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) instead, to get a persistent, managed entity from its ID. Or its equivalent in the Hibernate API: [`Session.load()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29).